# Counting value from one list column to another list column

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, workflow-activity, workflow-variable

I have 2 list, 1st have valie: ProductName, Price, Quantity.  In second list i have Customer, ProductName(lookup with ProduceName from list1), and QuantityCustomerBuying. Now, how can i make workflow so every time someone insert value in QuantityCustomerBuying that value also show in Quantity from list one. Exemple, if i have in Quantity(list1) value 20, and someone enter in QuantityCustomerBuying(list2) value 20, how can i add that value to Quantity from list1 (20+20=40). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a workflow that runs whenever an item in list 2 is created or updated.
2. In this workflow, get the values of the quantity of the current item and the quantity of the corresponding Product from list 1.
3. Add these values together.
4. Update the value of the corresponding Product in List 1 with the new sum.

Comment: Im so sorry, how can i "get" value can you show me exemple, im so sorry im new in sharepoint, so sorry again for wasting your time. Hope you will answer on this question soon.

Comment: Use the SharePoint Designer Workflow activity "Set Workflow Variable", and in the value > Define Workflow Lookup screen, select your first list as the Data Source. The "Field from Source" should be the field that contains the value you want.

In the "Find the List Item" section, you define WHICH item from the first list you want to use. Select "ID" in the field lookup, and in the Value lookup, use the Current Item's ProductName lookup. This tells SharePoint "Hey; lookup the value Quantity field in the Products list for the product I just selected in my new Customer Purchase record.